# How to run an event function once

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a lot of questions its all on java script (with some jquery)
first im trying to detect the mouse X cordinates when the mousemove on an element :

```
(function() {
 'use strict';

 $('.AnyElement').mousemove(function (e) {
 console.log(e.pageX)
 });

 })();
```

i want to detect the mouse  X once i know theres a functions like  mouseover etc...

but in general how to make this function run once and stop

Second when someone write :

```
 if (document.body = 1) {
  // do anything
 }
```

he is checking if document.body equal to 1

i see a thing in someone else code  i dont undertand here it is :

```
  if (document.body) {
  // do anything
  }
```

it doesnt matter what the function do , the thing is what he is checking  ???

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to your first question there are a few ways you could do it, one example would be to register the mousemove event and then remove the event after logging it once.

```
$('html').mousemove(function(e) {
      console.log(e.pageX);
      $('html').off('mousemove');
    })
```

Another method could be use the one event listener built into jQuery.

```
$('html').one('mousemove',function(e) {
  console.log(e.pageX);
});
```

In answer to your second question the first statement is looking for the length of the element, if the element exists it will generally be greater than 0. In the second statement document.body will return a boolean of true or false depending on whether or not the element exists. Again there are a million different ways you can do the same thing in Javascript.

Hope that helps!